# Axios post request throws bad request

Tags: reactjs, symfony

I am trying to get the jwt token when login is successful. It works, it returns token when I do it with curl, like this:

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" http://localhost/api/login_check -d '{"username": "admin@admin.com", "password": "000000"}'
```

I get result back:

```
{"token":"eyJ0eXAi..."}
```

But from the frontend application I get error:

```
{"error":{"code":400,"message":"Bad Request","exception":[{"message":"The key \"username\" must be provided."...
```

The code on the frontend looks like this:

```
let session_url = 'http://localhost/api/login_check';
let username =  'admin@admin.com'
let password = '000000';
axios.post(session_url, {
    withCredentials: true,
    headers: {
        "Accept": "application/json",
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
    }
    },{
        auth: {
            username: username,
            password: password
        }}).then(function(response) {
        console.log('Authenticated');
    }).catch(function(error) {
        console.log('Error on Authentication');
    });
```

I tried all the answers from the google, but I cannot find what am I doing wrong.

Comment: I think your request data (in `axios.post()`) should come before the configs like this: `(url: string, data?: any, config?: AxiosRequestConfig | undefined)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try axios like:

```
let session_url = 'http://localhost/api/login_check';
let username =  'admin@admin.com'
let password = '000000';

axios(session_url, {
  method: "post",
  withCredentials: true,
  data: {
    username,
    password
  },
  headers: {
    "Accept": "application/json",
    "Content-Type": "application/json"
  }
}).then(function(response) {
  console.log('Authenticated');
}).catch(function(error) {
  console.log('Error on Authentication');
});
```

I hope it helps!

Comment: It works, I will accept this answer, thank you Tamas a lot.

Comment: I'm glad I could help!

Comment: I did not wanted to give you a downvote, if you edit answer, I can vote again, not know what happend, I wanted to vote up.

Comment: Maybe it wasn't you, I asked whoever it was.